# App Engine and Bigquery authentication

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

We would like to implement an analytical tool with the aid of Bigquery and Cloud Storage services. The tool should run on App Engine and expose REST interface so that all requests go through that interface and subsequently are forwarded to Bigquery. Authorizing access to Bigquery should be based on App Engine service account (App Identity API). However, we also need to authenticate the tool clients. The client is always another app or service so OAuth 2.0 and web browser based authentication is not acceptable for us. Is there a way how we can implement such authentication and somehow bind it with Bigquery a Cloud Storage ACL?

Consider situation as follows. A client has been given Google account in our domain. It sends a request to our REST interface and provides credentials (email and password) with other details. The tool authenticates the client and sends request on its behalf to Bigquery (or Cloud Storage). In case that the client tries to access Dataset (Bigquery) or Bucket/Entity (Cloud Storage) without correct permission (set by means of Bigquery/Cloud Storage ACL), the access is forbidden.

Comment: Please explain "the client": You say: a) The client is always another app.... And b) A client has been given Google account in our domain.

Comment: Well, we suppose that it is possible to create a Google Account under our domain and use the account credentials (email, password) to authenticate a client (a application). However, we may be wrong and we will have to implement authentication on our own (e.g. by means of Spring Security). We are thinking about Google Accounts primarily due to their connection to ACLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we all need more details for this one.  How are you issuing the credentials to the clients?  Do you expect the operators of the client to know a username/password on your domain to authenticate the client to your service?

One option might be to issue the client an OAuth 2.0 refresh token, and they put that refresh token into their app configuration (securely), or you automatically bundle it as they download the app.  Refresh tokens are valid indefinitely unless revoked.

Then pass the OAuth 2.0 refresh token straight through the app engine app and onto BigQuery/Google Cloud Storage.  All ACLs (which client has permission to what) can then be handled natively in Cloud Storage/BigQuery.

You could also have them get the tokens themselves in a web browser, provided they have credentials.  They'll only need to do this a single time when setting up the application, and the token will be stored by the app.  More information in the guide on using OAuth 2.0 for installed applications:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp

Comment: Yes, we expect that the operators of the client know username/password but those credentials should be set on client side (static file, database entry, ...) without a need of internet browser.
<br/>
As I wrote above the primary reason for using Google Accounts is their connection to ACLs. However, the whole idea may be wrong and we will have to implement our own authentication and ACL mechanism (Spring Security) which will meet our needs much better.

Comment: Please explain why you hardcode the credentials? This looks like "old" clientLogin for installed applications, which is depricated.

Comment: Well we do not need to hardcode credentials if there is a different way how to authenticate a client without usage of a browser. Generally most of clients will run as scheduled jobs and that is why they need to authenticate even without a user interaction.

Comment: Typically, even for the clients running as scheduled jobs, you authenticate and authorize via a browser during the setup process.  Then the refresh token is stored and used indefinitely unless/until it is revoked.

Comment: Here's a good description of how you can use OAuth 2 for installed apps.  A web browser is needed on *some* machine for setup, but afterwards there is no web browser involved: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp

Comment: Thank you Ryan, the use case you described makes sense and I think that scenario could be possible for us. We will go through it an we will see.